# Example for an infinite sample space where one event has probability 1

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm writing some questions regarding sample spaces, and I have a solution to a problem that might be a bit complicated for the audience.

The question, essentially is "Is there an infinite sample space (i.e. infinitely many theoretical outcomes" where the probability of a single outcome is 1, and all other outcomes have probability 0?"

The example I am giving in my solution is the following: You are playing a game where you choose  random real numbers between [0,1] until you choose a number which is irrational.
In this case the sample space could be something like S={ irrational number, {1/2, irrational number}, {1/2, 2/3, irrational number}, ....}
Where the probability of the first event is 1, and all other probabilities are 0 but still in the space.

Does anyone have an example of such a sample space which would not rely on the students having seen uncountably infinite cardinalities...?

Comment: Flip a coin infinitely many times. Consider the event: tails occurs infinitely often.

Comment: Let $\Omega = \mathbb{N}$ and $P\{1\} = 1$.